# What can I make using the atronach forge

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I was walking through the midden a while back and saw the atronach forge and wanted to know what I can use it to make. I want to make some spell tomes and I heard I can make armour and daedra hearts. What can I make and how can I make these items?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are a bunch of Atronach Forge recipies, I suggest [consulting the UESP for the full list.](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Atronach_Forge)

The major highlights include:

- Daedric gear of all kinds
- Scrolls, staves, and tomes from the Conjuration tree
- A few alchemy ingredients
- All manner of hostile summoned enemies, which can be killed for their juicy loot
- The [Dovahcore helmet](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Fall_of_the_Space_Core,_Vol_1#Dovahcore_Helmet), a tie-in item from Portal 2 that is part of the Portal mod for Skyrim

Do note that some of the recipes require the Sigil Stone, which is a reward for a [particular quest.](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Conjuration_Ritual_Spell)  You'll need high Conjuration to get the quest and therefore the stone.

A few requested recipes:

- Storm Atronach Staff: Void Salt + Broom + (Orichalcum Ore or Orichalcum Ingot) + (Greater Soul Gem or Grand Soul Gem or Black Soul Gem)
- Storm Atronach Spellbook: Void Salts + Ruined Book + Deathbell + Mammoth Tusk

Comment: isn't the dovahcore a mod item? And if you can, can you tell me a recipe for storm atronach spell and staff

Comment: You forgot conjuration staffs.

Comment: @Matthew_m321: yeah, it's a mod item.  The mod is free and official, though, so I included it :P